# Combine the active background onclick and mouseover jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, mouseover

It's a bit hard to explain, but screen shots below show the result I want.

This is the result I want. The semi transparent blue background is activated when click on the image. For the other images, hide the caption and show the semi transparent blue background when hover.

[image]

But what I get is like this. I know this is causing by the `class "title"`, `100% height` and also the jQuery code. I have no idea how to combine the `mouseleave` and `click`. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hover effect
 $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('title');
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
 }).mouseleave(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(200);
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('title');  
 });

  //active after clicked
 $(".thumbnail").click(function(){ 
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
  if($(this).data('clicked')) {
   $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('title'); 
   $(this).children('span').children('span').toggleClass('background-active');
  }       
 });
});
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gallery-contents { position: relative; }

.gallery-item .title {
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0px; 
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#5ba4ee;
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}


.dark-background, .background-active {
 background-color: rgba(112, 158, 202, 0.8);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 30%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-contents">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
      <span>
        <span class="title">Gallery Item</span>
        <img src="https://cdn-main.123contactform.com/images3/landing_pages/free-small-business-forms.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following rule:

```
.background-active.title {
  background: rgba(91, 164, 238, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. It will make the caption background become transparent too. Please check my code

Comment: Then you can use rgba in background-color

background-color:rgba(91, 164, 238, 0.3);

Comment: Please check this, your method got this issue. https://preview.ibb.co/fdAkBG/3.jpg. I don't want the caption to be transparent.

Comment: Remove opacity and just use rgba, I checked on jsfiddle as well - https://jsfiddle.net/at02qma2/

Comment: Please check my code and my image clearly. This is the issue for your method https://preview.ibb.co/mZ5JWG/4.jpg. And this is not what I want

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle, apologise for not checking the complete page.

Comment: No worries. Do you have link? This jsfiddle you sent is not updated

Comment: You are welcome, can you please remove down-vote and up-vote it?

Answer (score -1):

Adding opacity:0.35 (or whatever desired value) will solve the opaque covering. If you get stuck vertically aligning the text to the centre,  take a look at CSS flexbox.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. It will make the caption background become transparent too. Please check my code